# What are libapp.so and libflutter.so?

Tags: android, flutter, apk

My Flutter application bundle contains native libraries, libapp.so and libflutter.so, each around 8-9MB. How can I find what is contributing to size of those files or which dependencies they're coming from?

Comment: The above mentioned files contains the compiled form of flutter framework and other native script in your project/ dependency.

Comment: Do you know how I can find which dependencies are contributing most to the size of those?

Comment: UPDATE: Looks like for a starter app itself (straight from 'flutter create') libflutter.so is 8.1MB and libapp.so is 4.1MB

Comment: flutter is a portable UI tool kit, so everything related to flutter has to be included with in the App. So every flutter app will have those .so files.

Comment: I can't find `libapp.so`, where could it be . Edit: Ohh, the debug APK doesn't have it, but the release APK does.

Answer (score 6):

`libflutter.so` (the flutter engine)

`libapp.so` (your code).

Answer (score 3):

**Flutter is a portable UI tool kit**, means everything that flutter depends upon must be included with in the APK file. So every flutter will have those mentioned .so files.

The mentioned `.so` files includes **Dart language dependency, skia engine, flutter framework, platform related native code etc.**