# How to extract source code from flutter APK or AAB file?

Tags: android, flutter, apk, mobile-application, android-app-bundle

is it possible to extract the source code from a flutter application's APK or AAB file?

If yes, then how

haven't tried anything yet. Looking for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Answer (score 1):

Extracting flutter code from APK seems to be impossible at this point, unless you have a [flutter debug apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53666487/flutter-debug-apk-decompile-to-get-the-source-code).

If you want native code, then you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file) to at least recover your assets and XML files and you might only need to re-write your Java code from scratch.

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct, but the second doesn't really match an app created using Flutter. From my understanding the Java/DEX code in an release Flutter app only contains the helper libraries from Flutter and other required libraries but not the user created code. The user created code is compiled into `libapp.so` https://stackoverflow.com/q/60217632/150978